# Was Soichiro Yagami that much close to his natural lifespan?

Tags: death-note

Shoichiro dies from wounds inflicted by Mello soon after making the Shinigami Eyes deal. Since he didn't even use the Death Note (nor was any DN used on the people involved in the incident) prior to his death, it can be assumed that the DN did not change the lifespans of anyone indirectly involved in some killing.

So because his lifespan was halved with the eyes deal and he dies a few hours/days later (lets assume he underwent surgery and a few days seems reasonable) was his natural lifespan that much short?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes and no. He himself said that he was thinking about suicide and that he probably would have done it within a few days. At this point, his lifespan was that short. But his "natural livespan" is unknown (and was probably longer) since his son's use of the DN led him into this situation.

Comment: Yeah it does get kind of weird when it comes to stuff like that; like when the DN says a death of one can't cause the death of another indirectly, but Light's killings DID kind of cause his Dad's premature death. I guess there's just a lot of factors that can't all be that accounted for...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a person who makes the eye deal with a shinigami gets their natural lifespan halved regardless of weather or not they technically use the Deathnote itself. By this logic Soichiro Yagami was only going to live a natural life of about three days max.